# Callback when a class is loaded

Tags: ruby

Is there a callback which can be executed when a  class is loaded. I am thinking something like this.

```
register_callback('Foo', :debug_message)

def debug_message
 puts "Foo has been loaded"
end

require 'foo'
```

Answer (score 8):

No, there is not. And there *cannot* be, for the simple reason that classes in Ruby are *open*: they are *never* fully "loaded", you can *always* add, remove, rename and overwrite methods at any later point in time.

For example, when is the following class "loaded"?

```
# foo.rb
class Foo
  def some_method
  end
end

# bar.rb
class Foo
  def some_other_method
  end
end

# baz.rb
class Foo
  def some_method
  end
end

require 'foo'
require 'bar'

require 'baz' if rand > 0.5
```

Comment: In practice and convention though if you named a file baz and had class Foo in there the PR would be rejected.

Comment: Sure, but what about a PR that had a file named `core_ext/foo.rb` in it? That is *very* common and is exactly the same thing.